Possible to replicate SQL Server Compress in C#?
How can I replicate the Compress functionality that can be used in a SQL insert query?
I know I can do the following:
INSERT INTO Player ([Name], [Surname], [Info])     
VALUES ('John', 'Smith', COMPRESS(N'{"sport":"Tennis","age": 28,"rank":1,"points":15258, turn":17}'))

But is there a way to replicate that T-SQL Compress method in C#, essentially compressing in-code before inserting into the database, and then being able to decompress it in a SQL read query?
I've tried multiple variations of the following code:
private readonly string _insertQuery =
    @"INSERT INTO Player([Name],[Surname],[Info]) 
      OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, inserted.Info
      VALUES(?,?,?)";

public void CompressAndWriteToDB()
{
    using OleDbConnection connection = new(_connectionString);

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = _insertQuery;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@name", "John"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@surname", "Smith"));

    var uncompressedString = "{\"sport\":\"Basketball\",\"age\": 45,\"rank\":1,\"points\":15258, turn\":17}";
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uncompressedString);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            gzipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@info", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
        param.Value = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    cmd.Connection = connection;

    connection.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteReader();
}

But when I try to decompress that data in SSMS using the T-SQL Decompress method, I only get weird characters:


nvarchar(max) is UTF16, try varchar(max). or encode in C# as UTF8. Also you should specify the param length as max like this cmd.Parameters.Add("@info", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = memoryStream.ToArray(); Also don't use OleDb instead use SqlConnection as that's the official library.

The N prefixing the literal in COMPRESS(N'{"sport":"Tennis","age": 28,"rank":1,"points":15258, turn":17}') indicates that the input is a National Character Literal (i.e.: nchar or nvarchar), so in C# you should use Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(uncompressedString) to get the same resulting bytes.

For the example string shown COMPRESS won't be particularly effective anyway. https://dbfiddle.uk/3Wlq_xCi You could consider using row compression on the table in order to get Unicode compression (which should be quite effective when most of the chars are just ASCII as in this example) or page compression to also potentially take advantage of compressing repeated strings across rows

I owe this answer to @AlwaysLearning. Thanks!
Basically, with the exact same code in the original post, I only had to change Encoding.UTF8 to Encoding.Unicode.
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(uncompressedString);

Now I can access the data in SSMS and decompress with
  SELECT [Id]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Surname]
  ,Info
  ,CAST(DECOMPRESS(Info) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS  AfterCastingDecompression
  FROM [MCrockett].[dbo].[Player]
  WHERE Id = 9

